# jquery click function not getting called

Tags: jquery

Why is the click function not called?

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#test').click(function () {
            alert('clicked');            
        });    
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <a id="test" href="#">Click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

You are adding an event to an element that doesn't exist yet. Wrap your event listener in a DOM-ready function or move your script tag below the element.

Answer (score 4):

you must have a closing script tag at:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript" >
</script>
```

and you must call your click binding in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test').click(function () {
        alert('clicked');            
    }); 
});
```

Comment: +1 for catching the closing script tag. Although technically it could work the way he's doing it (with self-closing `<script />`), as long as he's serving the page as `application/xhtml+xml`

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it this way:

```
$(function(){
    $('#test').click(function () {
        alert('clicked');            
    });    
});
```

in order to wait until DOM is ready to execute click function.